# Terminology for multi-cause changes

Tags: word-choice, terminology, technical, science

Is there any terminology or wording to describe the type of fundamental change of a system that is not the result of a single cause, but rather caused by many influences at interplay pushing from several directions that jointly make the status quo unsustainable, reaching a tipping point to force change?

So in a way, the opposite of a simple cause and effect relationship in say physics, and more the sort of causation in society or politics.

Comment: Economists use the 'multi factor model' in determining asset prices, and the term should transfer smoothly to other domains.

Comment: Multi-factorial is the term I would use.  Similar to Edwin's.

Answer (score 1):

As Edwin points out above "multi-factor model" is frequently used by economists.

In medicine (and other sciences), we call this *multi-factorial*.  For example:

> The link between diabetes and heart disease is multi-factorial.  It is not merely a simple cause-and-effect relationship.

You can also describe this situation as a *convergence* of causal factors.